# Is there a way to tell aws-cli to run a command to get a new session token if the current token is expired?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

At my work, our AWS authentication is integrated with our corporate sign-sign-on (SSO) system. In other words, when we want to access AWS, we do something that authenticates to our corporate system and then issues an AWS session token. The tokens expire after an hour so every so often an AWS command will fail because of an expired token and then I have to grab a new token and then repeat the command.

This isn't horrible, but being that I'm an engineer, I wrote a "aws" wrapper script that detects if the token is expired and if it is, it can run a configurable command to grab a new token and then execute the given command. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS=${AWS:-"/usr/local/bin/aws"}

if [ -z "$AWS_FORCE_GET_TOKEN" ] && ${AWS} sts get-caller-identity > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    ${AWS} "$@"
else
    CMD=$($AWS configure get get_token_command)
    echo "Error doing \"${AWS} sts get-caller-identity\"; Going to try running \"$CMD\"" > /dev/tty
    if $CMD 1>&2; then
        ${AWS} "$@"
    else
        echo "Failed to renew token with \"$CMD\"" 1>&2
    fi
fi
```

This script seems pretty good, though one limitation is that it only works if the "aws" executable is called. It will not work say if I have a Python program that uses `boto3` to interact with AWS.

Now I'm wondering if I missed something built into the AWS tools (`botocore` perhaps?) that would do this?

I'm a Python programmer so I'd be open to adding it if it's not already there and it's deemed to be a good idea. But I wanted to check first to see if it already exists and if it's a sane thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm realizing now that op offered a solution in the question. Seems like the CLI should do exactly that for sessions, but my bash skills are not confident enough to make that change.

I use this in my bash-profile:

```
function aws-refresh {
    echo "Verifying AWS token..."
    if identityOutput=$(aws sts get-caller-identity 2>&1); then
        echo "Token is valid"
    else
        echo "$identityOutput"
        echo "Token is invalid. Refreshing..."
        aws sso login
    fi
}
```

Then I can just run:

> aws-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `aws sts get-federation-token` CLI to get the token, you could set file with the token expire timestamp and have cron run the script to get new tokens every 20 mins; Compare the timestamp to the current time and update if they're going to expire.

> Expiration -> (timestamp)
>   The date on which the current credentials expire.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-federation-token.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [`saml2aws`](https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws) if you are using SAML authentication? otherwise, have a look at [`awsume`](https://github.com/trek10inc/awsume) project, which is small and neat, and may do what you want. It can also re-authenticate automatically when expired using a daemon.